# Disk wont show up for Mac OS install

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, mount

I received a Mac from a friend. When I tried booting, the Mac displayed a blinking folder with a question mark. So, I restarted the Mac with the <kbd>option</kbd> key pressed which booted to internet recovery. From OS X Utilities, I chose *ReInstall OS X*, but could not select an installation disk. I went back to OS X Utilities and opened the Disk Utility application. Below is the displayed structure.

```
500.11 GB Media
   Main //partition and also greyed out
SuperDrive //greyed out
   disk1
      Mac OS X Base System
```

I tried selecting `500.11 GB Media` and first aid, then repair disk executed and reported no errors.

I think the problem is the `500.11 GB Media` is not mounted, but the mount option at the top of the Disk Utility window is greyed out. 
I also tried erasing with *Mac OS Extended (Journaled)* selected. After starting to erase, an error message occurred:

> Could not mount disk0s2 with name Untitled after erase

How do I install macOS on the disk ?

Comment: Are you following a sequence of steps Apple lays out as Erase and Install? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315885/5472 If so, editing that in the post will help people answer it. If not - maybe that's the answer.

Comment: These are common symptom of failing I/O (likely a failing SATA cable or failing drive). [See here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375296/309630/) for my answer to a similar question.